# IPad mini repeating playlist without my permission

Tags: ipad, playlist

Previously, my iPad would play a playlist and stop. Now it keeps repeating endlessly. The only buttons I can find are play, stop, restart and skip ahead. There is no "repeat" button!
How do I make it stop repeating the playlist?

Answer (score 1):

There **is** a repeat button in Apple Music. It is shown in this image: http://cdn.cultofmac.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Repeat-icon.jpg

All you need to do is deselect that option. Don't be misled by the small '1' that shows up on the icon- you need to deselect it entirely.

*If you don't have a button, please provide a screenshot so I can give different advice, but you should have it... It's easy to miss though*

Comment: I am not signed up for Apple Music. I use iTunes.

Comment: Also I took a screenshot, but i don't know how to send it to you.